# Why my all sensors are not working at a time in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am stuck with my code for making fire detector with arduino. I have attached 5 fire Detector modules but, only one of them can detect fire at a time i dont know why.
can you please help me with my code.
I want all of my sensors work when fire detected.

```
int led = 13;
int fd1 = 2;
int fd2 = 3;
int fd3 = 4;
int fd4 = 5;
int fdMain = 6;
int fireDetected=LOW;

void setup() {
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fd1,INPUT);
  pinMode(fd2,INPUT);
  pinMode(fd3,INPUT);
  pinMode(fd4,INPUT);
  pinMode(fdMain,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void fire()
{
  if(fireDetected==HIGH)
  {
    //Serial.write("Fire Detected\n");
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);

  }else
  {
   // Serial.write("Fire Not Detected\n");
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  }

 }
void loop() {
  if((digitalRead(fd1)) or (digitalRead(fd2)) or (digitalRead(fd3)) or (digitalRead(fd4)))
  {
    //fireDetected=digitalRead(fd2); // This is working fine
    fireDetected=HIGH; // But this is not working at all
  }
  
   fire();
}
```

Comment: What is `or`? Did you mean operator `||`?

Comment: yes I mean '| |'

Comment: Please describe what do you expect and what do you observe in program behavior. `Only one of them` means one particular? Write values returned by `digitalRead()` to serial port for debugging and monitor them in serial terminal.

Comment: I want like fireDetected variable to be HIGH when any of the sensor senses fire..
but, it is not doing like that..
see this:
void loop() {
  if((digitalRead(fd1)) or (digitalRead(fd2)) or (digitalRead(fd3)) or (digitalRead(fd4)))
  {
    //fireDetected=digitalRead(fd2); // This is working fine
    fireDetected=HIGH; // But this is not working at all
  }

Comment: no.. 
I have also used || but, nothing happened .. please try to solve my problem..

Comment: @dimich [`or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or) is a valid operator in C++ and is equivalent to `||`

Comment: @LHLaurini Wow, this surprised me. Seeing it for the first time in about 20 years of learning C++ :) Thank you for correcting.

Comment: Thank you all.. I got my solution.
I changed || into &&.
i am surprised when i code into DEV C++ IDE i use || for any one statement to be true but, here is completely different .. BTW thanks

Comment: Side note: you can replace entire `fire()` function with single `digitalWrite(led, fireDetected);`

Comment: @LHLaurini   `or` *is* a valid c++ keyword.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/or

Comment: @SajjadAli  From your solution to the problem, I can say with certitude that I do not understand your question.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I guess TS wanted to turn on LED when all detectors activated simoultaneously, not one of them.

Comment: @dimich That's as good a guess as any, I guess... :)  Here's to hoping this code won't end up in my fire detector....  I mean, does the fire has to spread to all five rooms before waking me up?

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(fd1, INPUT);
  pinMode(fd2, INPUT);
  pinMode(fd3, INPUT);
  pinMode(fd4, INPUT);
  pinMode(fdMain, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void fire(int fireStatus)
{
  if (fireStatus == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
  else if(fireStatus == 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}
void loop() {
  if ((digitalRead(fd1) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(fd2) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(fd3) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(fd4) == HIGH) || (digitalRead(fdMain) == HIGH))
  {
    fire(1);
  }
  else
  {
    fire(0);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).